# display a drop down menu based on the first selection in php

Tags: php

i want to display the name based on previous selection of group name commerce.
i hard code the first option and want to select the data based on previous one
iam still confused how to do this... kindly guide me

```
       `<form action="" method="post">
         <table width="39%" height="67" border="0" align="center">
         <tr>
<td width="22%" height="27">Group</td>
<td width="33%"><select name="option"> 
<option>Commerce</option>
<option>Computer</option>
<option>Pre-engineering</option>
<option>Pre-Medical</option>
</select>
</td>

    <td width="8%">Name</td>
<td width="37%"> 
<? if ($option=='Pre-engineering') 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM std_reg where faculty='$option'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option>".$row[name]."</option>";}
?>
</td>
<td width="8%">Class</td>
<td width="37%"><input name="class" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td height="34" colspan="4"><strong><h3>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH" />  
     </h3></strong></td>

</tr>
<br />
<br />
```

'

Comment: what did you try and what you mean? to save previous value in store and when page is reloading then value in select must be checked?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the key here

```
echo "<option>".$row['name']."</option>";}
```